# How to play a audio file picked form a file picker in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I have file picker pick audio file from local storage and , result of the file picker is as follows

```
size: 1057931
name: "AUD-20190314-WA0019.m4a"
type: "audio/mpeg"
uri: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AWhatsApp%2FMedia%2FWhatsApp%20Audio%2FAUD-20190314-WA0019.m4a"
```

I am currently using react-native-sound for the playing the selected audio file from the picker

```
var whoosh = new Sound(audio, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
    return;
  }
  // loaded successfully
  console.log(
    'duration in seconds: ' +
      whoosh.getDuration() +
      'number of channels: ' +
      whoosh.getNumberOfChannels(),
  );

  // Play the sound with an onEnd callback
  whoosh.play(success => {
    if (success) {
      console.log('successfully finished playing');
    } else {
      console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
    }
  });
}
```

**(audio variable is the uri revived in file picker)**

But this approach doesn't play the audio file instead of playing , it leaves me the error

> failed to load the sound {message: "resource not found", code: -1}

What am I doing wrong, and how can I be able to play the audio file picked form the file picker?

Comment: you got the solution of this? @Jonny

Answer (score 0):

[`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-track-player`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-track-player)
This package will allow you to play audio file which have been picked from local storage.If you wan to pick audio file from local storage you can use **React native Document picker lib**